# Where is LogStash's log file on mac?

Tags: logstash

I am using the `.tar.gz` package of the LogStash 2.3. Where does the LogStash's log file locate? I can only find the related info for LogStash 5.0.
Thanks for your help!
Allen

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Found the answer myself. All the log are printed to terminal. However, if you want them to be printed to log file, you could specify `bin/logstash -l {path_to_log_file.txt}`